# While loop and only retrieve unique rows

Tags: php, mysql

If i have a column within a table that may repeat rows with the same value, how do I only retrieve unique rows doing a while loop? For example:

```
**NAME:**
__________
Bob
__________
John
__________
Bob
__________
Chris
__________
Jamie
__________
```

So in return it will display as Bob, John, Chris, Jamie using:

```
while($while = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )){ echo $while['name']; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` to your SQL query?

Comment: ^^^ eggs-ah-kit-ah-lee ^^^

Comment: Or before you loop, create an array.  In the loop, check to see if the name is in this array.  If it's not, echo it and add it to the array.  If it's in the array, don't echo.

Comment: Or fetch everything into an array first, then remove duplicates with array_unique() ... but seriously, just let SQL DISTINCT do the work

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha.... Thanks guys! I researched it but couldn't find the answer but maybe I was thinking too hard. @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just let the SQL query do the work here.  Just add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` to have SQL get you only unique results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM yourTable
```